# Get indexes of elements with specified value

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, c++17

I've got a huge vector of pixels of a PNG file. Index of the element is its position on the screen. I want to get every pixel's index with the same colour.

E.g.:

```cpp
std::vector<int> getColorIndexes(std::vector<Pixel>& vPngFile, PixelColor color)
{
    // do something
    return vColorIndexes; // Vector of indexes of pixel with specified color
}
```

What is the fastest way to do this?

**Edit**:
My attempt:

```cpp
std::vector<int> getColorIndexes(std::vector<Pixel>& vPixels, PixelColor color)
{
    std::vector<int> ret;
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < vPixels.size; ++i)
    {
        if (vPixels[i].color == color)
            ret.push_back(i);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing code to accomplish this?  Before worrying about the "fastest way", get it working in some fashion.  Look into speed if the resulting performance is not adequate.

Comment: offtopic - why send `std::vector` by a pointer rather than by a reference?

Comment: @Fureeish just a typo I suppose

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes, I did, but double for loop wasn't satisfying

Comment: @Ajdutt13 The code doesn't compile because of a typo. Ignoring that, this is probably already the fastest way to do it.